# how to bind AutoCompleteBox to a non-static List in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, autocompletebox

i am working with the AutoCompleteBox from the WP7 Silverlight Toolkit. i have seen examples where they bind a static list (non-changing List) of strings to the AutoCompleteBox. however, is there an example showing how to bind the AutoCompleteBox in a more dynamic way? my attempt below keeps throwing an InvalidOperationException: Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged event.

this is what i have in my xaml.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="tbQuery" TextChanged="tbQuery_TextChanged" />
```

in my code-behind, i have simulated going to a database or across the web as follows.

```
    private void tbQuery_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteBox acBox = sender as AutoCompleteBox;
        string txt = acBox.Text;
        if (txt.Length > 0)
        {
            //exception thrown below here;
            //_words is of type ObservableCollection<string>
            //earlier, acBox.ItemsSource was set to _words
            _words.Clear();
            _words.Add(txt + "a");
            _words.Add(txt + "b");
            _words.Add(txt + "c");
        }
    }
```

i also tried something like what is below too, but it didn't work as well. the same InvalidOperationException is thrown.

```
    private void tbQuery_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteBox acBox = sender as AutoCompleteBox;
        string txt = acBox.Text;
        if (txt.Length > 0)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(txt + "a");
            list.Add(txt + "b");
            list.Add(txt + "c");
            //exception thrown below here;
            acBox.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }
```

the demo in the toolkit only shows using a static resource, and most examples only show with a static list. is this because AutoCompleteBox is not to be used in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what is the point of changing the list on the fly? The autocompletion box filters automatically your list from the given itemssource.

Anyway, the TextChanged is first called **after** the AutoCompleteBox have attempted to filter out your items. If you press the back button after having typed in a few characters, you will see your generated items suggested.

You could most likely reprogram the AutoCompleteBox to your functionality (it's open source), but I think it would be better if you explained your purpose, so we can advice better.

Comment: if i have a list of 10,000 strings (which i have more), are you saying to actually load 10,000 strings and bind it to the AutoCompleteBox? how long will it take to load 10,000 strings? how much memory will this take? wouldn't it be more efficient if we can detect what the user typed in, perform a background filtering process, feed the UI a new (and shorter) list? i guess i'm understanding that this AutoCompleteBox is not dynamic like your AJAX auto complete widgets. if not, i just won't use it because it won't work but for trivial cases and won't scale.

Comment: 100*100 = 10000. And it's instant in both emulator and on a real device. (In reality, faster on a real device.). And I already pointed out, that it **does not** have the capability to bind dynamically (hence why I told you to reprogram it). But the whole idea of not fetching all data at once is silly. On a phone it's almost always better performance to get everything at once. And with 32 gb memory, you shouldn't worry about half a megabyte worth of strings.

Comment: i got SqliteSyntaxException: out of memory, i attempted to get only 1,000 strings from a table, (on the emulator). my sql is: select name from mytable, and mytable has 3 columns (id integer, name text, secondName text). this is using sqlite as the database. i guess this is a "sqlite" issue?

Comment: definitively a sqllite issue. I got apps that load larger databases of data from XML or JSON files into memory without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't actually need to reprogram the AutoCompleteBox. You can handle the Populating event to link the AutoCompleteBox to dynamically generated data.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.populating(v=vs.95).aspx) is what you are looking for. It's a good article with a good example. And as mention don't forget to call PopulateComplete() when the manual population operation is complete.

You can also set the ItemFilter property to a custom Filter for defining your own search logic. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.filtermode(v=vs.95).aspx) for details. Remember to set the FilterMode to Custom.